# WP CLI switching post status from publish to future not working?

Tags: wp-cli, post-status

I want to use wp cli to change post status from published to future, however it appears that once a post is published, it can no longer be switched to future. When I try to do this the post remains published. However it does appear that it is possible to switch from published to draft. Is this expected behavior to not be able to update a post status from published to future?

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt` to a date in the future. Otherwise the "future" date will be in the past, and the post will become published.

For example:

`wp post update 6868 --post_status=future --post_date="2023-08-26 15:11:29" --post_date_gmt="2023-08-26 22:11:29"`